# Why do I get an error unless I ask for the same input twice? (Java)

Tags: java, input, while-loop, conditional-statements

I run with program with only one `quit = input.nextLine();`, but this results in an error. However, if I use that line twice, no error occurs, and the program runs as intended. 
**Why?**

Error Message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at testjava.Test.main(Testjava.java:24)`

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            boolean x = true;
            boolean y = true;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (x) {
                while (y) {
                    System.out.print("Enter -1 to quit ");
                    int val = input.nextInt();
                    if (val == -1)
                        y = false;
                }  

                System.out.print("Are you sure you want to quit? (y/n) ");
                String quit = input.nextLine();
                quit = input.nextLine();

                if (quit.charAt(0) == 'y')
                    x = false;                  
            }
        }
```

Comment: You would do well to include *what error* you get.

Comment: You're right. An additional error was not including the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use input.next().

input.nextLine() skips the current line and outputs the line that was skipped.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I began learning java only a few days ago.

I'll mark this as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is your input for the number to quite (-1) isn't getting the end of line character which is only grabbed by your first `nextLine()`

I think you should get the whole line for the number then parse the int out:

```
 System.out.print("Enter -1 to quit ");
 String line = input.nextLine();
 int val = Integer.parseInt(line);

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

When you use just one `.nextLine()` Scanner skips the current line. And your input is never read. As a result `quit` becomes `""`. And you next code line throws exception.

```
if (quit.charAt(0) == 'y')
```

Use: [.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) as @UpAllNight suggests.